# Issue with setting Movie Player frame

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, mpmovieplayercontroller

In my ipad application I write a code to play a movie using `MPMoviePlayerViewController` . Here how I have achieve it.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:self.moviePlayingTempPath];

// Initialize the movie player view controller with a video URL string
self.playerVC = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];

// Remove the movie player view controller from the "playback did finish" notification observers
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self.playerVC
                                                name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                              object:self.playerVC.moviePlayer];

// Register this class as an observer instead
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(movieFinishedCallback:)
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                           object:self.playerVC.moviePlayer];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(moveiPlayBackStateChanged:)
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification
                                           object:self.playerVC.moviePlayer];



self.playerVC.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 600, 500);
[self.view addSubview:self.playerVC.view];

// Start playback
[self.playerVC.moviePlayer prepareToPlay];
[self.playerVC.moviePlayer play];
```

Issue is player always run in fullscreen mode. But I want to change the movie player frame size.
I tried following `[self.playerVC.moviePlayer setFullscreen:NO];`but no luck.

Here is the screen shot of my device. I use Xcode 4.6 and iOS 6 SDK.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able resolve this issue. There is a another view for movie player called MPMoviePlayerController.
Then I was able to change the frame of the movie. Here is the updated code.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:self.moviePlayingTempPath];

    // Initialize the movie player view controller with a video URL string
    self.playerVC = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];

    // Remove the movie player view controller from the "playback did finish" notification observers
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self.playerVC
                                                    name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                                  object:self.playerVC];

    // Register this class as an observer instead
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(movieFinishedCallback:)
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                               object:self.playerVC];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(moveiPlayBackStateChanged:)
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification
                                               object:self.playerVC];


    [self.playerVC setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleDefault];
    self.playerVC.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 600, 500);
    [self.view addSubview:self.playerVC.view];

    // Start playback
    [self.playerVC prepareToPlay];
    [self.playerVC play];
```